# Why does a Tor relay send more data than it receives?

Tags: networking, tor

I run a Tor relay. I have often seen that there is a significant discrepancy between the amount of data sent and that received. For instance, this morning log states:

```
Tor's uptime is 7 days 18:00 hours, with 551 circuits open. I've sent 167.80 GB and received 140.35 GB.
```

That's a nearly 20% difference. I had a view of a relay as little more than a passing station on the road, except for the occasional authentication to the network.

Does anyone know the origin and meaning of this discrepancy?  By the way, I am not hosting any hidden services.

Comment: It is normal that one receives less data then was send because of packet loss.
I think 20% is a bit too much to just blame packet loss but it could be.

Comment: Have you seen this question on [tor.stackexchange](http://tor.stackexchange.com/q/470) or is this question eventually from you?

Comment: No, I had not seen this. Thanks for pointing this out to me.

Comment: @nixda If you post your comment as an answer, I will accept it. Sorry for taking so long.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the link about being a directory service.

ToR adds an additional layer of encryption each hop a request goes through, that would mean that outbound traffic would be larger than the original request.

> TOR instead uses, at a minimum, three servers to pass your traffic on, each encapsulated with its own layer of encryption.

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/it-security/everything-you-need-to-know-about-using-tor/